# How do I use XSLT 3.0 map:remove?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I'm attempting to remove an item from an XSLT 3 map, but I keep running into what to do with the output of the map:remove function. At this point, I'm using a throwaway variable to make sure I don't return anything on the output.

```
<xsl:if test="map:size($aMap) > 0">
    <xsl:variable name="throwaway" select="map:remove($aMap, map:keys($aMap)[1])"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Where/how do you want to use the map from which you remove an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps are immutable so while you can call `map:remove($aMap, map:keys($aMap)[1])` without storing the result of that call it doesn't change the map the variable `aMap` is bound to, you need to store the result of the `remove` call, in a new variable, or rebind the existing variable; so

```
    <xsl:variable name="aMap" select="map { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 }"/>
    <xsl:message select="map:remove($aMap, 'b')"/>
    <size>{map:size($aMap)}</size>
    <xsl:variable name="aMap" select="map:remove($aMap, 'b')"/>
    <size>{map:size($aMap)}</size>
```

gives

```
   <size>3</size>
   <size>2</size>
```

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for that! For some reason I was under the impression "map:remove" would return a single map entry of the removed item.